# putting bunch of vectors in one array in python with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 8 vectors(x,y) and I want to put them in one numpy array. how should I do it?how can I access them individually?
[0 0] [ 3.  0.] [ 3.  0.] [ 4.5         2.59807621] [ 4.5         2.59807621] [6 0] [6 0] [9 0]

Comment: What do you mean by "vector"? Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `numpy.array` [command](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)

```
 array=np.array([(0, 0), ( 3., 0.), ( 3., 0.), ( 4.5, 2.59807621), ( 4.5, 2.59807621), (6, 0), (6, 0), (9, 0)])

array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 6.,  0.],
       [ 6.,  0.],
       [ 9.,  0.]])
```

To access them just refer to them individual `array[0]`, `array[1]`, etc.